# Maximal subgroups of affine general linear groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

For an odd prime $p$, let $G$ be the affine general linear group of degree 1 over $\mathbb F_p$, i.e., the semidirect product of $\mathbb F_p$ with $\mathbb F_p^{\ast}$ where $\mathbb F_p^{\ast}$ acts on $\mathbb F_p$ by multiplication. What are the maximal subgroups of $G$? In particular, how many are there? Could anyone provide references where the subgroup structure of this group is discussed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $G = {\rm AGL}(1,p) = N \rtimes H$, where $N$ is the translation subgroup, which is cyclic of order $p$, and $H$ is cyclic of order $p-1$.

Let $M$ be a maximal subgroup of ${\rm AGL}(1,p)$.

Case 1. If $M$ contains $N$ then $M/N < G/N \cong H$ is a maximal subgroup of $H$, so it has index $q$ in $H$ for some prime $q$ dividing $p-1$. There is one maximal subgroup of this type for each prime divisor $q$ of $p-1$.

Case 2. If $M \cap N = 1$, then $|M|$ divides $p-1$, so $M$ is a conjugate of $H$. There are $p$ such conjugates of $H$ in $G$.