# Find normal groups using homomorphism

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Well, I have a group: $G = \{ ax + b \mid a,b\in \mathbb{Z}/29\mathbb{Z}, a - {\rm invertible \space element}\}$ (by composition). My task is to find all subgroups with order of $58$, which of them are normal?
The main idea: build the homomorphism from $G$ to something, use [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8Bzu.png).
So, my question is what homomorphism should I use?

Answer (score 0):

The group $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_{p}^{\ast}\ltimes \mathbb{F}_p$ and has order $p(p-1)$ (you have $p=29$). It is called the affine group of degree $1$, and can be represented as
$$
G\cong \left\{\begin{pmatrix} a & b \cr 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\mid a\in \mathbb{F}_p^{\ast},b\in \mathbb{F}_p\right\}\subseteq GL_2(\mathbb{F}_p).
$$
This can be helpful to study subgroups of $G$. You are looking for subgroups of order $2p$. For the maximal subgroups see here:

[Maximal subgroups of affine general linear groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1669965/maximal-subgroups-of-affine-general-linear-groups)

You are in Case 1 of Derek's answer.